# What are valid fields in .ssh/config file?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm putting together a config file for ssh on Ubuntu 16.04. I've created the file as `~/.ssh/config`, and I've had success adding some basic servers that only required a `HostName`, `Port`, and `User`. Now I'm trying to set default landing directories (i.e. `user@my.server.com:/default/landing/path`). Is that possible?

Additionally, I'd like to be able to disable `PubkeyAuthentication` and instead use password authentication. When using `scp` I can do this as

```
scp -o PubkeyAuthentication=no file user@my.server.com:/path/to/dest
```

Is this possible in the config file?

Long story short: what is the set of possible options for the ssh config file?

Comment: Short answer: It depends what version of SSH you're using!

Answer (score 4):

The file contents are documented as

```
man 5 ssh_config
```

that documents both the default configuration (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) and the user's one (`~/.ssh/config`).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'd overlooked a key page when searching for this info: all valid fields can be found on [OpenSSH's website here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/).

To my specific questions:

`PubkeyAuthentication no` is how to turn off public key authentication

There evidently is no way to specify the directory, but [this StackOverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387872/ssh-config-file-alias-to-get-to-a-directory-on-server) gives a workaround.